# Find notification source(/post id) using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asynchronous, notifications, facebook-javascript-sdk, promise

I am using the facebook graph api to query all of the user's notifications - so far so good. Now I want to query the post that caused that notification. In [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/notification) documentation on facebook it says I will get `response.data[i].object` object where the whole post will be, but unfortunately I don't get the `.object` at all. This is my function for getting notifications:

```
getUserNotifications: function () {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        FB.api(
            "/me/notifications", {since:'last week','limit': limit},
            function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }  
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

And here are all the permissions I use:

```
FB.init({
    appId: id,
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true, // parse XFBML
    read_stream: true,
    manage_notifications: true,
    user_groups: true

});
```

Of course, every permission is later injected in the login scope:

```
FB.login(function(response){},
                    {scope: 'user_status,user_photos,read_stream,publish_stream,
                             user_likes,publish_actions,
                             read_friendlists,rsvp_event, user_groups'
                    });
```

Comment: What _do_ you get as a response?

Comment: Usualy [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dY5bh/1/), which I am wondering how to get the id of the post from. Sometimes though, only if it is on my wall I get it right with the .object like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Rg9GS/)

P.S.: I want to get every notification like the 2 one, the one on my wall

Comment: Now I even lost .object on the wall notification... I can't really understand why it is there sometimes and sometimes not... :/

Comment: The first output you’ve shown is a _combined_ notification for _multiple_ things that have happened, it says the user “posted 9 photos in […]” – for such notifications that encompass _multiple_ involved objects, you can’t expect to get a _specific_ object.

Comment: But in facebook, when you click it it goes to a post with those 9 pics and this is what I am trying to achieve...can I at least somehow get the id of the post from the notification.link string? I tried everything but I can't query it and I really need to visualise it as if a user clicked the notification in facebook and create a facebook-like post-review...